# Syntax to run a distinct GROUP_CONCAT in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT campaign.id AS campaign_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(utm.campaign) AS utm_campaign
FROM [email_event]
WHERE (TIMESTAMP BETWEEN SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1412136000) AND SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1414814340))
GROUP BY campaign_id;
```

And I would love to run a distinct GROUP_CONCAT, as now same entries are repeated in the output.

**UPDATE**

I've extended your solution to this:

```
SELECT campaign.id AS campaign_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(utm.campaign) AS utm_campaign,
       GROUP_CONCAT(utm.content) AS utm_content
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT 507 AS campaign.id,
             'remarketingemail' AS utm.campaign,
             'newsletter_feb' AS utm.content),
     (SELECT 508 AS campaign.id,
             'remarketingemail' AS utm.campaign,
             'newsletter_jan' AS utm.content),
     (SELECT 508 AS campaign.id,
             'remarketingemail' AS utm.campaign,
             'newsletter_feb' AS utm.content),
     (SELECT 508 AS campaign.id,
             'adwordscamp' AS utm.campaign,
             'cyber_monday' AS utm.content) )
GROUP BY campaign_id;
```

But now I got repeated values for utm_campaign.

```
+-----+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 507 | remarketingemail                         | newsletter_feb                       |
| 508 | remarketingemail,remarketingemail,adw... | newsletter_jan,newsletter_feb,cyb... |
+-----+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

this is the raw output on the subquery, before qroup by

```
+-----+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 507 | remarketingemail                  | newsletter_feb                |
| 508 | remarketingemail                  | newsletter_jan                |
| 508 | remarketingemail                  | newsletter_feb                |
| 508 | adwordscamp                       | cyber_monday                  |
+-----+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you please share the results of the sub-query too?

Comment: @N.N.  result of the subquery is the 3 rows you can deduct from my table above.  The problem is that "remarketingemail" is being duplicated in group_concat, and don't know how to get unique.

Comment: can you please share the source data? from your question is hard to understand the cardinality of each field.

Comment: if utm.campaign to campaign_id has 1:1 or m:1 relations, you can use a different aggregation function such as MAX().

Comment: @N.N. the relation it's m:n, I added a pure query that you can test with. And I repeat, I am after distinct values group_concat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a subquery to group by and get distinct values. something like this:

```
SELECT campaign.id AS campaign_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(utm.campaign) AS utm_campaign
FROM
    (Select campaign.id,utm.campaign
    FROM [email_event]
    WHERE (TIMESTAMP BETWEEN SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1412136000) AND SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1414814340))
    GROUP EACH BY campaign.id,utm.campaign)
    GROUP BY campaign_id;
```

another option for few aggregated fields is to do it in stages...

```
SELECT campaign_id ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(utm_campaign) as utm_campaign,
       utm_content
       From
(SELECT campaign.id AS campaign_id,
       utm.campaign as utm_campaign,
       GROUP_CONCAT(utm.content) AS utm_content
FROM
    (
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT 507 AS campaign.id,
           'remarketingemail' AS utm.campaign,
           'newsletter_feb' AS utm.content),
  ( SELECT 507 AS campaign.id,
           'remarketingemail2' AS utm.campaign,
           'newsletter_feb' AS utm.content),
  (SELECT 508 AS campaign.id,
          'remarketingemail' AS utm.campaign,
          'newsletter_jan' AS utm.content),
  (SELECT 508 AS campaign.id,
          'remarketingemail' AS utm.campaign,
          'newsletter_feb' AS utm.content)
      )
    GROUP BY utm_campaign,campaign_id)
    GROUP BY utm_content,campaign_id
    ;
```

Comment: See my update to the question, when having two group_concats the distinct is not working well.